# WMI Event Watcher Task

Tags: ssis, wmi

I have set up a WMI Event Watcher Task using `WqlQuerySourceType` of Direct Input and the below as `WqlQuerySoruce`, but it does not detect a new file when I add it and just keeps running.  Any ideas what I can do?

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DirectoryContainsFile"
AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent = "Win32_Directory.Name=\"c:\\\\test\""
```

Comment: Thank you for your response bkVnet.  I made your change but, still had the same result.

Comment: hi Query looks perfect.  check if your loop is workings fine .or file path is correct.

Comment: Thank you sandeep!  It does appear to be something with the path.

Comment: you can add a lookup in which you put true = true